# Debugging/Testing code of two arrays

Tags: java, debugging, testing, merge, mergesort

I made a mergesort which mergesorts an array in 3 parts instead of two in order to sort it and I wrote some code to test my mergesort if it works properly. Here is the code for the testing:

```
while (true){

    Random rand = new Random();

    int[] randArray = new int[rand.nextInt(2000)];

    for (int i = 0; i < randArray.length; i++) {
        randArray[i] = rand.nextInt();
    }

    int[] temporary = new int[randArray.length];

    System.arraycopy(randArray, 0, temporary, 0, randArray.length);

    mergesort(randArray);

    Arrays.sort(temporary);

    if (Arrays.equals(randArray, temporary)){
        System.out.println("YES");
    } else {
       break;
    }

    }       
}
```

What I'm doing is everytime create an array of up to 2000 integers and fill the array with random integers, then store that array in the temporary array, after that use my mergesort in the original array and use the `Arrays.sort()` method for the temporary array, then if the two arrays are equal print YES or else break from the while loop.

By now it hasn't broken from the while loop and indicating that my algorithm is correct so I am asking if I did right here and wrote the testing code correctly.

EDIT: It is printing YES constantly without breaking from the loop so I believe it is working but I am asking so I can be sure

Comment: If this isn't printing `YES` or ending, then that implies to me that there is some sot of infinite loop in your `mergesort()` function, you may need to post that if you want help with this issue.

Comment: no it is printing YES constantly

Comment: The only way your loop ends is when it breaks out of the loop, and the only time it does that is when your merge sort fails.  You could change the loop to a counted loop and then it would only test a certain number of random arrays, is that what you want?

Comment: No I want it to test indefinitely, so when the program stops I will know it was because of some error I made. I am just asking if I did this correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test code seems good to me, and that means your algorithm is mostly good as well. On the other hand, please don't get me wrong, but this kind of testing can be considered only a quick and dirty check. If you want to do proper testing, you should test the following:

- happy path with simple examples
- boundary conditions
- error conditions

You should also consider using an automated test framework like JUnit.

And finally, using random input in a test is not a good practice, as the result of the tests can change from run to run.

Comment: I am a novice programmer and I have never actually used an automated test framework, to be honest I didn't know such thing exists. Is it easy to use for a novice programmer like me?By the way I changed the output from YES into a number which indicates how many correct arrays I have sorted. The else remained as it is I just did that to see how many I have by now and I'm over two million different tests, so I guess I could be good but anyway is JUnit easy to use or will I get confused?

Comment: JUnit is very easy to learn, just give it a try. It is integrated with many IDEs, like eclipse. It will be necessary in your later career, if you plan to have a career on java development anyway.